# Parse.com unable to get username from Parse.User.current?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Using javascript, after the user logs in successfully, I tried to extract the username as below:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
name = user.getUsername;
```

The value of name is: **`function (){return this.get("username")}`**

If I use `name = user.getUsername();`

The value is **undefined**!!

Comment: In the first case, you're just retrieving the function and not executing it. In the second case, you are properly executing the function, but it looks like the properties for the user haven't been populated yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
user.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
    var name = fetchedUser.getUsername();
}, function(error){
    //Handle the error
});
```

Here the issue is `Parse.User.current()` method will return a user object if the user logged in or signed up successfully, but this object wont be having all the details of the user object. In order to get all the object properties you have to call `fetch` method on a user `Object`.

Comment: thanks so much for sharing this. I have spent 14 hours looking for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

try

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var name= user.get("username");
```

Comment: Wrong place though :)